# Android Gallery - Replace Bitmap in ImageView after scrolling stopped

Tags: android, animation, scroll, gallery, zooming

I've programmed a zoomable gallery with several images.

- The images can be zoomed.
- Zoomed images can be dragged.
- If the image is not zoomed, the gallery can be scrolled.

The layout consists of a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` (the name of the gallery) and the `Gallery` itself.

An item in the gallery consists of a `RelativeLayout` containing a `FrameLayout` with the `ImageView` in it (I read I need the FrameLayout for zooming) and a `TextView` to show the zoom state of the image.

I've used a custom `View.OnTouchListener` to implement the zooming.

Now I was trying to replace the image in the `ImageView` **after** the gallery has stopped scrolling with a high res picture so the user can zoom in much better/further.

I did this with the `OnItemSelectedListener` and `setCallbackDuringFling` to false.

Even this works fine if you fling the screen fast.
But if you keep your finger **on** the display and move it **slowly** to the edge, the `OnItemSelectedListener` is fired **before** the next item reached the center and the scrolling animation stops. Instead the gallery jumps like it looses touch contact and centers the next item in the gallery immediately. Also the `OnItemSelectedListener` is called more than once on the same item when moving the finger slowly (I avoid this problem by saving the position of the last selected item).

So (*long story short*) I was looking for a callback/listener to the "scrolling/snap-to-grid" effect of the `Gallery`. I also tried an `AnimationListener`, but the gallery returns null when i call `getAnimation` on it.

I'm desperate here... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I'm now using the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with the custom callbacks in the `OnPageChangeListener`:

- `onPageSelected`
- `onPageScrollStateChanged`
- `onPageScrolled`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a slight change to your method. For your Gallery, override `onScroll(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` and `onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` have them return their super but on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || MotionEvent.ACTION_UP set a moving flag to true || false respectively.

Now in the BaseAdapter for your Gallery in the getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method when you are returning your image view return the low res ImageView if the moving flag is true else return the high res.

Comment: Thanks for you tip, but the `getView(...)` is called as soon as the next item becomes visible (is scrolled in). Also I already tried to make the image dependent from gestures. But that also didn't work for me, because if you have MotionEvent.ACTION_UP the gallery may still be scrolling to center the current item. I want to replace the image **after** the item is centered.